# How to customize SpringWebFlux WebClient xml+rss JAXB deserialization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-webflux

Look as json configuration example for spring webflux client:

```
   ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies
        .builder()
        .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {

        //how to do the same but xml?
        clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        }).build();

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(strategies).build();
```

The same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769301/how-to-customize-springwebflux-webclient-json-deserialization) but for jaxb xml serialization. Is there decoder implementation for JAXB and xml? Is it possible to use [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) as decoder for webclient to make spring boot controller and client implementation consistent?

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess are the the `Jaxb2XmlDecoder` and `Jaxb2XmlEncoder` classes from the `org.springframework.http.codec.xml` package:

```
ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(configurer -> {
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
        })
        .build();
```