# Different JSON (de)serialization configs on different endpoints using Spring WebFlux

Tags: jackson, spring-webflux

My micro service needs to communicate with 2 different services over HTTP. 1 has an API contract with snake_case JSON, while the other uses camelCase. How can I configure WebFlux to deserialize and serialize JSON with a certain Jackson `ObjectMapper` on a set of functional endpoints, while use another one on different endpoints?

The WebFlux documentation [shows](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-config-message-codecs) how to wire in another ObjectMapper, but this applies to all the endpoints of my API. So right now either all my JSON in snake_case or in camelCase. Cant find any resource to solve this issue, but it must be doable right?

Update: to make it clear I want to configure the web server which receives the requests from other services, not the webclient for sending http requests myself. I know how to do the latter.

Comment: This might help you, took me 1 min to google https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769301/how-to-customize-springwebflux-webclient-json-deserialization

Comment: this customizes the webclient HTTP coding, I already do this, but this is not what I need. The stuff I linked is about customizing the encoding for the incoming request to the server, and their responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is not the cleaned up solution, I will use this solution from our library, but the basic gist of my work around looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class Handler {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public Handler(@Qualifier("snakeCaseWrapper") ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> returnUser(final ServerRequest request) {
        //REQUEST DESERIALIZATION
        var messageReader = new DecoderHttpMessageReader<>(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(mapper));
        var configuredRequest = ServerRequest.create(request.exchange(), List.of(messageReader));

        //RESPONSE SERIALIZATION
        return configuredRequest.bodyToMono(UserDto.class)
                                .map(userDto -> {
                                    try {
                                        return mapper.writeValueAsString(userDto);
                                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        //properly handle the error here
                                        return "";
                                    }
                                })
                                .flatMap(json -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                               .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(json))
                                );
    }
}
```

This is the only way I could find to programatically choose which kind of `ObjectMapper` I want to use for a specific endpoint/handler method for request deserialization. For response serialization, the trick was to first use the `ObjectMapper` to serialize the response body to a `String`, and put that `String` into the response with `BodyInserters.fromObject(json)` .

It works, so I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `@JsonNaming` annotation on the classes you want to serialize/deserialize and specify what type of naming strategy you want.

[jackson-advanced-annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)

Comment: thanks for the tip! sadly there are plenty of data classes the APIs share

Comment: well i am pretty convinced there is no built in way of setting specific serialization/deserialization basen on path mapping alone. So good luck then

Comment: I did find a workaround solution. But I only have a proof of concept yet. Once I clean it up and bake it into my service, i'll post it here.