# SpringBoot WebTestClient - How to use expectBody in graphql API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, graphql

With a REST API and Spring Boot WebTestClient I can easily get back the object parsed from the returned JSON like this:

```
  Person person = webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/person/3")
                .exchange()
                .expectBody(Person.class))
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
```

With graphql the json is wrapped inside of a data attribute like this:

```
{ 
  "data" : {
    "person" : {
      "name" : "Foo"
    }
}
```

So it doesn't work with

```
      ...
      .expectBody(Person.class))
```

as the JSON parser is starting with "data" and not with "data.person".

How to achieve this to parse the JSON result directly and return the Person object?

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL has default [response](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#response) structure and any successfully response is returned in `data` block like below

```
{
  "data": { ... },
  "errors": [ ... ]
 }
```

So use `@JsonRootName(value = "person")` and configure the `ObjectMapper` with `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` feature

```
@JsonRootName(value = "person")
public class Person {

  // properties

  }

 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
 om.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
 om.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
```

Comment: But how to connect this with webtestclient?

Comment: see this just set the `ObjectMapper` to `webtestclient` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769301/how-to-customize-springwebflux-webclient-json-deserialization @Janning