# Spring WebClient.Builder timeout defaults and overrides for runtimes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.4 with Java 17. The [Spring `WebClient` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient) says to use the injected `WebClient.Builder`:

> Spring Boot creates and pre-configures a `WebClient.Builder` for you. It is strongly advised to inject it in your components and use it to create `WebClient` instances. Spring Boot is configuring that builder to share HTTP resources, reflect codecs setup in the same fashion as the server ones …, and more.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient.runtime) also says:

> Spring Boot will auto-detect which ClientHttpConnector to use to drive WebClient, depending on the libraries available on the application classpath. For now, Reactor Netty, Jetty ReactiveStream client, Apache HttpClient, and the JDK’s HttpClient are supported.

This is a bit unclear to me. I had read in books and articles that Spring Boot will use Netty automatically for `WebClient`. But does this mean that without further configuration, the latest Spring Boot will use the JDK `HttpClient`? Note that I have included `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in my project, but nothing specifically relating to Netty.

Furthermore the [Spring Reactor documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout) tells me that I can configure a connection timeout like this if I am using the Netty runtime:

```java
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
```

But what is the timeout default already, if I don't add this code? And if I don't like the default and want to use this code, how do I override the default `WebClient.Builder` (mentioned above) without building one from scratch (and possibly negating all the other benefits)?

So let me summarize my doubts, based upon all this slightly ambiguous documentation:

1. If I only specify `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, is Spring `WebClient` using Netty or JDK `HttpClient`. (If it's using Netty by default, why does the documentation even mention JDK `HttpClient`? How would I force JDK `HttpClient`?)
2. What are the default HTTP connection timeouts with the preconfigured `WebClient.Builder`, and where is this documented (or how can I find this out in the source code)?
3. How can I override just the connection timeout for the preconfigured `WebClient.Builder` which is injected into the Spring context automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `HoaPhan` has already pointed out the code that checks for the presence of different `HttpClient` classes in the classpath. Based on those checks, the initialization of a `ClientHttpConnector` object happens in [this method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v6.0.8/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultWebClientBuilder.java#L337-L353). As we can see in the linked code(included below), a `JdkClientHttpConnector` gets initialized if none of the other libraries are present in the classpath

```java
    private ClientHttpConnector initConnector() {
        if (reactorNettyClientPresent) {
            return new ReactorClientHttpConnector();
        }
        else if (reactorNetty2ClientPresent) {
            return new ReactorNetty2ClientHttpConnector();
        }
        else if (jettyClientPresent) {
            return new JettyClientHttpConnector();
        }
        else if (httpComponentsClientPresent) {
            return new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector();
        }
        else {
            return new JdkClientHttpConnector();
        }
    }
```

Looks like netty gets added as a transient dependency when using `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. So to force the code to use the JDK HttpClient, you can do either what `HoaPhan` suggested or exclude netty dependencies from the classpath, which on gradle would look something like below:

```
    implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux') {
        exclude group: 'io.projectreactor.netty'
    }
```

With the above exclusion and with none of the other `HttpClient` libraries present in the classpath, a `WebClient` bean like below should use the JDK HttpClient:

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
```

2. The default connect timeout, if using the netty client, is 30 seconds. The timeouts are documented [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-timeout)
3. Overriding the timeout in the preconfigured `WebClient.Builder` bean can be done using the same code you have included in the question, substituting `WebClient.builder()` with the injected `WebClient.Builder` bean. Something like below:

```java
package io.github.devatherock.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);

        return builder
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To create `WebClient` objects with different configurations from the single pre-configured `WebClient.Builder` bean, we'll need to clone the builder bean first

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient accountsClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);

        return builder.clone()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebClient payrollClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000);

        return builder.clone()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

To set timeouts and other customizations to the pre-configured `WebClient.Builder` bean, the simplest way would be to provide a custom `WebClientCustomizer` bean, like `HoaPhan` pointed out, as `spring-boot` [applies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.0.6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientAutoConfiguration.java#L49-L56) all customizers to the `WebClient.Builder` bean when it is created. Then the customized `WebClient.Builder` bean can used to create as many `WebClient` objects as required. Sample below:

```java
package io.github.devatherock.config;

import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WebClientCustomizer timeoutCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);
            builder.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public GoogleService googleService(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        WebClient googleClient = builder
                .baseUrl("https://www.google.com")
                .build();

        return new GoogleService(googleClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public BingService bingService(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        WebClient bingClient = builder
                .baseUrl("https://www.bing.com")
                .build();

        return new BingService(bingClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Overriding the timeout in the preconfigured `WebClient.Builder` bean can be done … substituting `WebClient.builder()` with the injected `WebClient.Builder` bean." Right, that now gives me a `WebClient` that I can inject everywhere. But what if I want to keep injecting a `WebClient.Builder` everywhere, using all the defaults Spring Boot already configures for `WebClient.Builder`, except now the injected `WebClient.Builder` has a timeout configured? For example, individual beans may want to generate their own `WebClient` instances with a default API URI, using the injected `WebClient.Builder`.

Comment: The `WebClient.Builder` interface exposes a `clone()` method that can be used to create multiple `WebClient` beans with different timeouts, from the single builder bean injected by spring boot. Will add an example

Comment: It's good to know I can clone the builder, but that still doesn't address what I want. Your example still shows making a `WebClient` available for injection. I want to do the _opposite_ of clone. I want to expose a single `WebClient.Builder` (like Spring does already) that I can inject anywhere, but I just want it to have a timeout specified (in addition to the other default settings). Maybe you're saying that I can't do that, and I have to live with injecting a `WebClient` and cloning it each time.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I misunderstood your 3rd question twice! A `WebClientCustomizer` should give you what you are expecting. I have updated the answer again, hopefully correctly this time

Comment: In my experience, it actually makes more sense to have @Config prepare different WebClient, eg: AuthClient, AuthzClient, AttributeClient, OrderClient, FeatureFlagClient... because each of them has a very different nature of connection/cache/security/retryStrategy/rate-limit... 

Should you feel it'd be practical to have 1 client to rule them all, maybe raise an issue/pr on the spring repo or reactor-netty repo(you can introduce sys env change default behavior of netty construct, bypassing spring). Maybe there are others who have the same need.

Comment: I'm only now getting a chance to try this. It looks like you are creating a whole new `HttpClient`. But doesn't default `WebClient.Builder` create an `HttpClient` already? Does it have any special settings it uses? If I create an `HttpClient` manually, won't that discard any special setup that Spring is doing with the default `HttpClient` used for the default `WebClient.Builder`? The point here is to use _all_ the default settings that Spring uses, and only modify the connection timeout. Does Spring perform any setup on its `HttpClient` that I would be discarding with this approach?

Comment: No, the `WebClient.Builder` bean initialized by spring-boot just calls `WebClient.builder()` which returns a `DefaultWebClientBuilder` object without any customization.  The only other thing spring-boot does is apply all the available `WebClientCustomizer` beans to the created WebClient.Builder object, one of which is what we are using to set the timeout. The `clientConnector`, which wraps the `HttpClient`, gets initialized only when creating the `WebClient` object, by calling `build()` method on the WebClient.Builder bean

Comment: I wanted to stop by and say thanks. The `WebClientCustomizer` works well with other customizers such as `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`, as I explain in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76765254).

Answer (score 4):

1. If you check
   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultWebClientBuilder.java#L56
   you'll see its selection of Webclient impl base on whether they are in the classpath. Notice at the top it does

   ```
   static {
   ClassLoader loader = DefaultWebClientBuilder.class.getClassLoader();
   reactorNettyClientPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", loader);
   reactorNetty2ClientPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("reactor.netty5.http.client.HttpClient", loader);
   jettyClientPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient", loader);
   httpComponentsClientPresent =
           ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.CloseableHttpAsyncClient", loader) &&
                   ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.hc.core5.reactive.ReactiveDataConsumer", loader);}
   ```

Technically you could force it to use JDK http client (since 6.0 https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0-M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/JdkClientHttpConnector.html)

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
ClientHttpConnector clientConnector = new JdkClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(clientConnector).baseUrl("http://google.com").build();
```

2. The default timeout if not specified is up to the implementation of a particular HTTP client, for example for Netty, it would be indefinitely (it would wait indefinitely for a response).
   [image]
   Though the best practice is to configure timeout base on your knowledge of the particular service. See note in next the point.
3. You could use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientCustomizer.html. Though in my experience it's better to construct webclient toward each remote service with timeout and other option(proxy, TLS, cache ...) base on the SLA of that particular target(some service have longer response time, some requires proxy, some required private certificate, some use MTLS ...). Webclient like Netty have full fledge [built-in metric](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/1.1.3/reference/index.html#_metrics_3) that can be enabled so that you can start with best guess and by time, observe and adjust the config of webclient to better suite the particular client-server dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this information. @devatherock gave me a cleaner way to switch to the JDK client, and provided examples for the web client customizer, so they get the bounty. I appreciate your information, too.